# YouTube API: retrieving videos, where's the video URL?

Tags: youtube-api, google-data-api

I'm playing with YouTube API. Using the following URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RayWilliamJohnson/uploads, how do I get the video URLs? The URLs all seem to have the schema https://. Shouldn't there be an http:// only?

Comment: I didnt knew that youtube has any API. Thanks for this question!

Comment: Almost everything has an API nowadays.

Comment: Please show your code for retrieving the feed. Tip: you can use json by adding `?alt=json` to the url, it it's better in your case than XML. Still, I'd prefer Zend Gdata, which has functions for things like this.

Comment: I don't need to show that code. There are several ways to do it. You can even just do it from the browser. All I want to know is how to get the URL for the video (the http version). Also, why do you think JSON is better than XML?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I assumed you have some code ready already and would like to simply add this functionality to it. As you said, there are many ways to retrieve the feed, so what method should the answerer use? You don't even tell the language you work in.

Comment: @MarttiLaine - please click on the link I provided. You will see the results in the browser. I'm seeing the exact same thing in my code (what language I'm using doesn't matter). I just need to know where in the response is the URL I need so I can extract it.

Comment: Or why the response doesn't have the data I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `<entry>` tag, which gives each video's information. `<id>` tag inside `<entry>` should be what you need.

For example, `<entry><id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/u5yEXai8MoQ</id>`

Comment: So I have to go to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/u5yEXai8MoQ and then parse that for the actual URL of the video? If I retrieve 50 videos from the first URL I call, I then then to go through each of the entries and make an additional URL call? That doesn't seem practical. I feel like I should just parse for the video id in the first response and just build the video URLs myself. That seems to be overly complicated though. Maybe my initial URL is wrong?

Comment: From https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RayWilliamJohnson/uploads, you will see all the video entries uploaded by this user. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want the URL to the videos. If you know XPath, please refer to it that way. If not, JSON notation is fine. I just don't see it there.

Comment: Isn't http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX the URL to the videos? If this is what you want, you just need to know the video IDs, and they can be found in the feed.

Comment: So, parse the video id (it exist in many places, so doing a combination of XPath + regex should be easy) and then build the URL? Seems unnecessary. I'm wondering why isn't the URL just already there.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem with just adding `youtube.com/watch?v=` to the video IDs.